# Kafka as readstream source always returns 0 messages in the first iteration

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have a Structured Streaming job which has got Kafka as source and Delta as sink. Each of the batches will be processed inside a `foreachBatch`.

The problem I am facing is I need to have this Structured Streaming configured to be triggered just once, but in that initial run Kafka always returns no records.

This is how I have configured the Structured Streaming process:

```
 var kafka_stream = spark
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_bootstrap_config)
      .option("subscribe", kafka_topic)
      .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
      .option("groupid", my_group_id)
      .option("minOffsetsPerTrigger", "20")
      .load()

val kafka_stream_payload = kafka_stream.selectExpr("cast (value as string) as msg ")

kafka_stream_payload
    .writeStream
    .format( "console" )
    .queryName( "my_query" )
    .outputMode( "append" )
    .foreachBatch { (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) => process_micro_batch( batchDF ) }
    .trigger(Trigger.AvailableNow())
    .start()
    .awaitTermination()
```

I tried to configure the Kafka `readStream` to pick a minimum of 20 new messages by using `"minOffsetsPerTrigger", "20"`. However, every first iteration it keeps returning 0 new messages.

In case I remove the `.trigger(Trigger.AvailableNow())` option, during the second (and following) iterations the process will be reading an average of 200 new kafka messages.

Is there a reason why I am getting 0 records during the first iteration?, and how can I configure the `sourceStream` to enforce a minimum number of new messages?

Answer (score 0):

Since you configured (.option("startingOffsets", "latest")) it's possible that you can get 0 messages for the first iteration, if messages are not available on time in the Kafka topic. try to check for (.option("startingOffsets", "**earliest**")).

or add ("auto.offset.reset", "earliest")

or make sure the data is getting published to the Kafka topic continuously then start your consumer

Comment: The Kafka topic is receiving more than 10 new messages per second. First run always return 0, following iterations between 200 and 400 new messages.